# external disk suddenly unmounting

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive

Platform: Ubuntu 9.10
Disk Brand/model: [WD My Book](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?modelno=wd5000d032-000&x=0&y=0)

The external hard disk suddenly unmounts after a while. I suspect it's due to it "sleeping" to save power.

I don't recall the problem having occurred before the upgrade to Karmic.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Is this a seagate/maxtor hard drive?

Comment: lol totally a seagate/maxtor common problem.

Comment: Updated question, with link to model page

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a Seagate External or Seagate Freeagent drive. There are multiple articles which discuss this issue.

- http://www.engadget.com/2007/12/07/seagate-freeagent-drives-not-down-with-linux/
- http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1039498/seagate-snubs-linux

Solution below includes the Maxtor OneTouch.

- http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-usb-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg52993.html
- http://www.nslu2-linux.org/wiki/FAQ/DealWithAutoSpinDownOnSeagateFreeAgent

Comment: I have a Seagate FreeAgent Pro that has been disconnecting after a while--even when I'm in the middle of running badblocks on it!  I'll try out the solutions you've posted.

Comment: Update: this didn't seem to fix my problem with a Seagate FreeAgent Pro 500 GB over USB.  Power management was already disabled on my drive, but the drive seems to go to sleep anyway, even if it's in use.